# How to compile a C program that use libpcap to armv7?

Tags: c, linux, arm, libpcap

I made a simple C program that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pcap.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

    pcap_t *handle;
    handle = pcap_open_live(NULL, BUFSIZ, 1, 1000, errbuf);
    if (handle == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open devic: %s\n", errbuf);
        return(2);
    }

    struct pcap_pkthdr header;
    const u_char *packet;
    packet = pcap_next(handle, &header);
    /* Print its length */
    printf("Jacked a packet with length of [%d]\n", header.len);
    /* And close the session */
    pcap_close(handle);

    return(0);
}
```

And I tried to compile it to my SAMA5D2 card using the following instructions:

step 1 - download the libpcap library and compile it to arm:

```
wget https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/archive/libpcap-1.9.1.tar.gz
tar zxf libpcap-1.9.1.tar.gz
cd libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --prefix=$(pwd)/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc make install
```

step 2 - compile my program:

```
 arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc program_pcap.c -lpcap -L./libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib
```

But I got this error message:

```
./libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpcap.so: file not recognized: file format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would be thankful if someone could tell me what I did wrong. :)

Comment: It's likely using the host's linker. Try adding `LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc` to your first command line too. By the way you don't need to set the CC, LD etc. after you ran `./configure` because it will remember what value you told it to use. A good idea is to check what the format, architecture, etc. your library has using `readelf`.

Comment: Hey Jorge, Thank you for your answer! unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: So what does `file ./libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpcap.so` say?

Comment: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=aa78b1d684a4876650bb96d8948dc213573c44fe, with debug_info, not stripped

Comment: Is this on Linux? If so, on what version of what Linux distribution are you doing this?  If not, on what version of what other operating system are you doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application does not correspond to the target platform of the library you want to link. It is recommended to use the “file” command to compare

```
file ./libpcap-libpcap-1.9.1/libpcap-1.9.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libpcap.so
```